# Google Spreadsheet Formula - SUMIFS - Broken?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

Can somebody please explain this error? It does not make any sense to me.

What I know so far is that works perfectly fine if I don't have the ' " ' in my 'Criterion'. I have tried every single escape character that I could think of as well as browsing google for a solution, but to no avail.

To make things even better, the same escape character that I am using below works with SUMIF, but apparently not with SUMIF**S** which is so stupid that I can't believe that this is the issue. there must be something I'm missing.

[image: Screenshot of Formula HERE ( Easier to Read )]

**Formula:**

```
=SUMIFS(T:T,S:S,"=10"" Tab",U:U,"<>GSM") + SUMIFS(Y:Y, "=10"" Tablet", Z:Z,"<>GSM")
```

> **Error being thrown:**
>
> "SUMIFS expects all arguments after position 3 to be in pairs."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is caused by your 2nd sumifs formula. most likely it should be:

```
=SUMIFS(T:T, S:S, "=10"" Tab",    U:U, "<>GSM")+
 SUMIFS(T:T, Y:Y, "=10"" Tablet", Z:Z, "<>GSM")
```

Comment: Never noticed that I missed the "sum_range" bit of the formula. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is prompted because after you have introduced your `summing range` you have to introduce the other input arguments in pairs. As 1st criteria range with 1st criteria expression, 2nd criteria range with 2nd criteria expression.

If you want you can take a look [at the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en)

For example:

[image: Sample of SUMIF function]

In your case your formula feels slightly off because you are not having the right number of parameters.

In this part you don't even have a criteria for the range.

```
SUMIFS(Y:Y, "=10"" Tablet", Z:Z,"<>GSM")
```

If the summing range and the criteria is the same you need to make it explicit.

Comment: "In this part you don't even have a criteria for the range."

This was it. I can't believe I missed that.. I guess I got so many errors along the way with that escape character and the formula differences from SUMIF to SUMIFS, that I just wanted to blame it on Google :)) Thanks Raserhin